# Merge [acer-aspire-one] and [aspire-one]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[acer-aspire-one](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/acer-aspire-one) - 40 questions tagged.

[aspire-one](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aspire-one) - 2 questions tagged.

They're identical, please merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags have been merged & synonym created.